# how to make funnel in python that branches off?

Tags: python, plot, graph, plotly, visualization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEk0D.png)How do I make a funnel that branches off into multiple branches and effectively visualize this?

I have tried ploty but the functionality doesn't support this.

For example, if I have 100 cancer patients and 50 of them go into treatment and 50 do not.

For the 50 that go into treatment 49 are in remission and 1 is not in remission.

This seems simple enough but I am having trouble effectively visualizing this.

because I am not able to get the treatment outcomes as a branch of treatment
Here is the code I've tried:

Here is what I've tried

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Treatment',
    orientation = "h",
    y = ["Treatment Decision", "Outcome"],
    x = [50, 0],
    textinfo = "value+percent initial"))

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'No Treatment',
    orientation = "h",
    y = ["Treatment Decision", "Outcome"],
    x = [50, 0],
    textposition = "inside",
    textinfo = "value+percent previous"))

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'Remission',
    orientation = "h",
    y = ["Treatment Decision", "Outcome"],
    x = [0, 49], 
    textposition = "outside",
    textinfo = "value+percent total"))

fig.add_trace(go.Funnel(
    name = 'No Remission',
    orientation = "h",
    y = ["Treatment Decision", "Outcome"],
    x = [0, 1],
    textposition = "outside",
    textinfo = "value+percent total"))

fig.show()
```

Comment: I assume that plotly funnel diagrams are designed to have the same categorical variables in each layer. So if you modify the data specification, you can create a graph that is closer to what you intend. However, the respective percentages, etc. will not be displayed correctly.

Comment: Please refer to the information as it was developed in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wSvcuwGfR7VpPuZqLnUMnV70gZh6XJ90?usp=sharing). If you check Colab, it will disable the link.